# Can't get access to iterator inside template function

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary

Let I have the following code

```
#include <map>
template <typename Value>
static void Get(std::map<int, Value> & map)
{
    typename std::map<int, Value>::const_iterator it;
    it _it = map.find(1);
}
void main()
{
    std::map<int,std::string> _map;
    _map.insert(std::pair<int,std::string>(1, "1"));
    Get<std::string>(_map);
}
```

I get the error for the line

```
it _it = map.find(1);
```

Why so?

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you meant to define `it` as a type, you need `typedef`

```
typedef typename std::map<int, Value>::const_iterator it;
```

If you wan to define `it` as variable:

```
typename std::map<int, Value>::const_iterator it;
it  = map.find(1);
```

Or just write:

```
auto it = map.find(1);
```

Also, `void main()` should be `int main()`.

Comment: Or, just write `auto it  = map.find(1);` and forget the typename and typedef for a moment.